# Responsive voice jquery plugin not working inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, responsivevoice

im trying to make responsive voice read out each sentences  and there must be a 1 minute gap between each readouts.

```
                function read(){

             responsiveVoice.speak('قلم','Arabic Female');
            }


            var a = [1,2,3];

            $(a).each( function(){ 

            setTimeout(function(){ read(); }, 1000);

            });
```

currently it only plays once and in the other two loops getting error

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().

i also can't make it read anything passed to it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem is that you used `.each()` method not correctly because `$(a)` try to target selector but not an array.

From [jQuery.each() doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

*jQuery.each( array, callback )* where

**array**: Type: Array - The array to iterate over.

**callback**: Type: Function( Integer indexInArray, Object value ) - The function that will be executed on every object.

So, try this:

```
$.each( a, function(){ 
   setTimeout(function(){ 
      read(); 
   }, 1000);
});
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: im still getting the error :  Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().

Comment: Yeah, i have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after googling a bit i found this answer

[setTimeout inside $.each()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270874/settimeout-inside-each)

Basically, you need to increment the timer.

```
$.each( a, function(i){ 
   setTimeout(function(){ 
      read(); 
   }, i*1000);
});
```

So first loop is 1 second. Loop 2 will be 2 second.

Here is my sample code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
                    console.log(text)
                    responsiveVoice.speak(text, 'Swedish Female', {rate: 0.7}, {pitch: 2});
               }, i*6000);
```

Each speech takes approx 5 seconds. I use 6 second because i want to add some pause each line.